# ACF - image as a subfield

Tags: wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

so after a lot of researching and trials and errors, I come to you. This seems to be very basic and still no luck. The issue is that my image does not appear and in the console it gives me an <img src (unknown) />.

So, in my ACF, I have a field called first_row that contains sub fields, one of the is called left_side_bg. It's attributes are all standard, and is set to return an Image Array. As a side note, I have another subfield called left_side_text.

On my php file, I'm trying to retrieve it like this:

```
<?php 
    $info = get_field('first_row');
    $left_side_bg = get_sub_field('left_side_bg');
?>

<div class="single-banner">
  <img src="<?php echo $left_side_bg['url']?>" alt="">
     <div class="inner-text">
        <h4><?php echo $info['left_side_text']; ?></h4>
     </div>
</div>
```

The left_side_text shows fine, but no luck with the image... is there anywhere I can double check or debug this better, or am I fetching the data incorrectly?

As a side note, I have tried different ways to retrieve the image by changing to Image URL, Image ID (in the ACF custom editor) and so on, but no luck, so I returned to the original format I tried to get the image the first time with all the ACF fields as default (getting the Image as an Array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_sub_field()` is meant for Repeaters and Flexible Content (rows). I assume `left_side_bg` and `left_side_text` are in the same group. Therefore, try it like so:

```
<?php 
    $info = get_field('first_row');
?>

<div class="single-banner">
  <img src="<?php echo $info['left_side_bg']['url']?>" alt="">
     <div class="inner-text">
```

It also makes a difference to what your Return Value is configured. I hope it is set to "Image Array". Otherwise, you might have to omit the `['url']` if it's "Image URL" instead.

If that isn't working, it might be a good idea to post a screenshot of what your ACF field configuration (field group) looks like.

Comment: thanks so much, that worked fine! I wasn't away of the extra ['url'], how could I have printed on the console so I could have figured that I needed that extra field?

Comment: If by console you mean within the PHP code and have WP_DEBUG_LOG active, a nice way of printing stuff is using `error_log( json_encode( $info ) );` You would've seen the entire array with the `left_side_text` and `left_side_bg` keys along with the `['url']` key this way.

Comment: Usually, if you have groups like these, they come back as arrays and any images or Post Objects are returned within this as nested arrays.